# Best Application Delegate Practice

Tags: iphone

I have been making a few apps here and there, and I know my way around. What has always confused me is accessing global attributes, and where the best place to set them are. I have a few questions about accessing things and how to access them.

Do you have to include your application delegates header file into any other other file you want to access it in? Say I have a view controller, that I would like to use, do I need to include the .h inside my view controller's .h? Or can I set the:

```
@class AppDelegate;
```

Can you only access the delegate by typing out:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

EACH and every time? Is that something I just have to get used to? Or could I set the following in my implementation in each .h:

```
AppDelegate *delegate;
```

And inside the `init` function, put the singleton instance to that variable?

Sorry if this was off structure, but I think it's a logical question people have a problem encountering and solving.

Comment: What kind of “global attributes”? Such thing can usually be designed better, without accessing the application delegate or any other shared structure all the time.

Comment: I am not talking about the app delegate specifically, but say I have a view controller that pushes another one, I would like to push things around is all from one controller to the next.

Comment: An object-oriented way to pass data between controllers is to explicitly define properties in the next controller, which the previous controller can set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to reconsider how you are using the App Delegate? It sounds to me like perhaps you are not making a very good class design.

Regardless, here's a way to make it easy. Don't put this in init just use it when you need it.

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Naturally, replace MyAppDelegate with the actual class name of your app delegate.

Comment: And to not repeat yourself, you might put that code in a class method in your delegate like so:

    + (MyAppDelegate*)applicationDelegate
    {
        return (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to add the code to use a properly casted app delegate reference as a `#define` in the app delegate header file, so after including it you can do something like:

```
MYAPPDELEGATE.customProperty = blah;
```

However I tend to favor just writing out the line that John presented, as use of #defines confuses code completion which I find more annoying than just typing the line.

As also mentioned, if you have a ton of references to the app delegate you may want to restructure to keep some of those references closer to home.